# QuickSight report as an pdf format rather than CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to Save **QuickSight** report as an pdf format? 
We have option to save quicksight dashboard as CSV format but if we need to store it in PDF how we can do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do a print, and then "print as pdf" on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can now schedule an email report of the dashboard in QuickSight and configure that to attach a PDF version also. Not sure if this was available when you asked the question but this would be the simplest mechanism at the present time. Unfortunately for me there's apparently no way to send a report from QuickSight with a CSV or other attachment type, which would be very helpful also.